# How do I extract information from this source code. I want to extract the Name , address,course,institute type from this link

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I want to extract the Name, address, course, institute type from this code. I am not able to do it I guess it because of the table. Every time I try it gives me a blank list. I don't know what to do

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body ">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_pnldefault">

            <table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege" class="table table-bordered table responsive" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlstCollege$ctl00$hdnInstituteId" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_hdnInstituteId_0" value="968  " />
                  <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_hlpkInstituteName_0" href="CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=968  ">**A R INSTITUTE OF PHARMACY , BIJNOR (968)**</a>
                  <br />
                  <b>Location:</b>
                  <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblAddress_0">**TAJPUR** </span>
                  <br />
                  <b>Course:</b>
                  <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblCourse_0">**B.Pharm**,</span>
                  <br />
                  <b>Category:</b>
                  <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblInstituteType_0">**Private**</span>
                  <br />
                  <b>Web Address:</b>
                  <a id="lnkBtnWebURL" href='' target="_blank"></a>
                  <br />
                </td>
              </tr>
```

```
res = requests.get('http://kyc.aktu.ac.in/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
weblinks = soup.find_all('a', attrs = {'id':'ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_hlpkInstituteName_0'})
pagelinks = []
for link in weblinks:     
 link = link.find('a') 
 pagelinks.append(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body "><div class="row"><div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_pnldefault"><table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege" class="table table-bordered table responsive" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;"><tr><td><input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlstCollege$ctl00$hdnInstituteId" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_hdnInstituteId_0" value="968  " /><a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_hlpkInstituteName_0" href="CollegeDetailedInformation.aspx?Inst=968  ">**A R INSTITUTE OF PHARMACY , BIJNOR (968)**</a><br /><b>Location:</b><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblAddress_0">**TAJPUR** </span><br /><b>Course:</b><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblCourse_0">**B.Pharm**,</span><br /><b>Category:</b><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblInstituteType_0">**Private**</span><br /><b>Web Address:</b><a id="lnkBtnWebURL" href='' target="_blank"></a><br /></td></tr>'

soup = bs(html , 'lxml')

name = soup.find('a', id='ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_hlpkInstituteName_0').text.strip()
address = soup.find('span', id= 'ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblAddress_0').text.strip()
course = soup.find('span', id = 'ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblCourse_0').text.strip()
institute_type = soup.find('span', id = 'ContentPlaceHolder1_dlstCollege_lblInstituteType_0').text.strip()

print(name)
print(address)
print(course)
print(institute_type)
```

Output:

```
**A R INSTITUTE OF PHARMACY , BIJNOR (968)**
**TAJPUR**
**B.Pharm**,
**Private**
```